# Flute fingering for slurred 3rd octave: E to B flat?

Tags: fingering, flute

This is in the Flute 1 part for Tchaikovsky's Nutcracker Suite "Danse des Mirlitons".

[image]

(We are in D major, this excerpt cuts of the key signature!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, from the E, I would try just lifting both middle fingers and seeing if the stock fingering for the "lower" B-flats works for you.  As I recall, it's harder to get to speak, but it certainly seems technically convenient here.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the picture but I can sort of imagine what you're talking about, perhaps lift the left middle finger and slide the right one to the first trill key?  That's the best I can do, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've played the Nutcracker many times in the past 5 years (and am playing it now), and I've never had to use any alternate/shortcut fingering here, which I often find for my students in many other passages.  Just use the regular fingerings and anticipate the high Bb a little, but still make sure the high E sounds in time.

Answer (score 0):

The standard fingerings should work fine here. You don't need to completely lift RH2, you can just roll it onto the trill key.

Another contributor suggests overblowing the second octave B-flat, but that has the problem that the note speaks badly and you're liable to miss it.

If the standard fingering is too hard, an alternative is to play the E by lifting LH3 from the D (maybe add a little more breath support on the E)